# Create war without manifest

Tags: ant

I need to create a war file through ant build without a manifest file. I want the war to me created without the manifest file.

I am using  tag in build.xml to create the war.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `<zip/>` task with `.war` extension for `destfile` attribute to achieve the same result as the `<war/>` task (**without** `manifest.mf`).

`<zip destfile="..\...\`**`WarFile.war"`**`basedir="..\basedir" update="true"/>`

in case `WarFile.war` already exists, although you've written `I need to create a war file` , the attribute `update="true"` will be of use (by only updating and not overwriting the file).

Answer (score 0):

All a war file is is a zip file in a specific format. That is libraries go in a particular place, class files go elsewhere, etc. The `<war>` task has sub-entities like `<classes/>` and `<lib>` that make configuring a war file correctly without knowing exactly where everything has to go.

However, you can correctly format the war yourself, and use `<zip/>`.

Why don't you want a manifest file? A manifest, if you don't specify anything, will contain nothing but the Java version used for the build, and the Ant version and won't affect the execution of your war at all.

What you can do is put useful information into the manifest. For example, we use Jenkins for our builds, and we put in the Jenkins project name and the build number which helps us understand what was included in the war.

There's no reason not to use a manifest file. And, a manifest file can contain useful information (which is accessible to the Java program too).